# How can I find words by using its part in DataFrame's each column in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, search

I'm making "title searcher" function in R and have difficulty.

My plan is like this.

1. receive title name from user.

   `search_keyword = readline(prompt = "Books Title")`
2. Base on search_keyword, function looks around database.
3. and it returns title's "Full-name" and its "rank" from database's each column.

### The shape of Database looks like below.

rank |________       Jan  ___________|_____________       Feb      | ....

1 | You can do Coding : it is easy .| Article = (revised version.)

2 | Article = (revised version.) .......| (New)The Story of programmers

3 | .................................................                        |You can do Coding : it is easy

belows are my wanted result.

- search_keyword = "Article"
- then, it returns ...

  Input Keyword : "Article"

  Searched : "Article = (revised version.)"

  change of ranking [ Article = (revised version.) ]

  Jan : 2

  Feb : 1
  ..
  ..
  ..

  (if it has no ranking in september,

  sep : Out of chart)

In my case, my countries words have no Capital differences.(No concept of Capital)

sample data is like below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q534W.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages. See the code below:

```
# Sample input
df<-data.frame(rank=1:3,
               Jan=factor(c('You can do Coding : it is easy','Article = (revised version.)','The Story of programmers')),
               Feb=factor(c('You can do Coding : it is easy','The Story of programmers','Article = (revised version.)'))
               )
  rank                            Jan                            Feb
#1    1 You can do Coding : it is easy You can do Coding : it is easy
#2    2   Article = (revised version.)       The Story of programmers
#3    3       The Story of programmers   Article = (revised version.)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

search_term<-'You'
df %>%
  gather('month','title',Jan:Feb) %>%
# rank month                          title
# 1    1   Jan You can do Coding : it is easy
# 2    2   Jan   Article = (revised version.)
# 3    3   Jan       The Story of programmers
# 4    1   Feb You can do Coding : it is easy
# 5    2   Feb       The Story of programmers
# 6    3   Feb   Article = (revised version.)
  filter(grepl(search_term,title))
# rank month                        title
# 1    2   Jan Article = (revised version.)
# 2    3   Feb Article = (revised version.)
```